# Maui image doesnt changed when image source changed

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

So i have some properties which i need only on specific pages so i decided to use inheritance inside my model. When the user selects an image for the first time, everything works fine, the image is displayed immediately, but if I try to select another image to replace the existing one, the path to the image changes, and the image in the UI itself remains the one that the user selected the first time. I don't understand why it doesn't work, because the source is marked with the observable object attribute and should have changed. But when i debugging my app and adding image with same binding, all works fine, image same as user select. I'm attaching the code of my model, View and ViewModel to make it as clear as possible. Please explain what I am doing wrong and what I should do in this situation

Model code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace Bibliomatic_MAUI_App.Models
{
    public class TestQuestionResponce
    { 
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public string UserAnswer { get; set; }
        public Guid TestId { get; set; }        
        public double PointsPerAnswer { get; set; }        
        public TestQuestionType TestQuestionType { get; set; }
        public TestResponce Test { get; set; }       
        public ICollection<TestAnswerResponce>? TestAnswers { get; set; }
    }

    [ObservableObject]
    public partial class TestQuestion : TestQuestionResponce
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        public string userAnswer;

        [ObservableProperty]
        public int questionNumber;

        [ObservableProperty]
        public string questionImageSource;
    }


    public enum TestQuestionType
    {
        OneAnswerQuestion,
        MultipleAnswerQuestion,
        PairsQuestion,
        OpenEndedQuestion
    }
}
```

My ViewModel code:

```
using Bibliomatic_MAUI_App.Models;
using Bibliomatic_MAUI_App.Services;
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Storage;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using Syncfusion.Maui.DataSource.Extensions;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Bibliomatic_MAUI_App.ViewModels
{
    [QueryProperty(nameof(Test), "Test")]
    public partial class TestEditorViewModel : ObservableObject
    {        
        public List<TestQuestionType> TestQuestionTypes { get; set; }

        [ObservableProperty]
        public TestResponce test;      

        [ObservableProperty]
        public TestQuestionType selectedQuestionType;        

        private readonly TestService testSerice;
        private readonly TestSaverService testSaverService;            

        public TestEditorViewModel(TestService testService, TestSaverService testSaverService)
        {
            this.testSerice = testService;
            this.testSaverService = testSaverService;

            TestQuestionTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TestQuestionType))
                                     .Cast<TestQuestionType>()
                                     .ToList();

           
        }

        [RelayCommand] 
        public void AddTestQuestion()
        {        
            var questionToBeAdded = new TestQuestion
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Question = string.Empty,
                Test = Test,
                TestId = Test.Id,
                QuestionNumber = Test.TestQuestions.Count + 1,
                TestQuestionType = SelectedQuestionType,
                QuestionImageSource = string.Empty,
                TestAnswers = new ObservableCollection<TestAnswerResponce>()
            };
                     
            Test.TestQuestions.Add(questionToBeAdded);
        }       
       

        [RelayCommand]
        public void DeleteTestQuestion(TestQuestion selectedTestQuestion)
        {
            Test.TestQuestions.Remove(selectedTestQuestion);

            Test.TestQuestions.Where(tq =>
            {
                var testQuestion = tq as TestQuestion;
                return testQuestion.QuestionNumber > selectedTestQuestion.QuestionNumber;
            })
            .ForEach(tq =>
            {
                var testQuestion = tq as TestQuestion;
                testQuestion.QuestionNumber--;
            });                    
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public void AddTestAnswer(TestQuestion selectedTestQuestion)
        {
            selectedTestQuestion.TestAnswers.Add(new TestAnswerResponce
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Answer = string.Empty,
                Variant = string.Empty,
                Message = string.Empty,
                TestQuestion = selectedTestQuestion,
                TestQuestionId = selectedTestQuestion.Id,
                IsCorrectAnswer = false
            });          
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public void DeleteTestAnswer(TestAnswerResponce selectedTestAnswer)
        {
            var selectedTestQuestion = selectedTestAnswer.TestQuestion;
            selectedTestQuestion.TestAnswers.Remove(selectedTestAnswer);
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public async void PickImage(TestQuestion selectedTestQuestion)
        {            

            //This method should work without this line of code because the file should be overwritten
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedTestQuestion.QuestionImageSource))
            {               
                File.Delete(selectedTestQuestion.QuestionImageSource);
                selectedTestQuestion.QuestionImageSource = string.Empty;
            }
            

            var image = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
            {
                Title = "Please select image"
            });

            if (image == null)
                return;
            
            var stream = await image.OpenReadAsync();
            var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
            await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            
            var filename = $"{selectedTestQuestion.Id}.jpg";

            string filepath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, filename);
            await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(filepath, bytes);            

            selectedTestQuestion.QuestionImageSource = filepath;
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public void Unfocused()
        {            
            testSaverService.SaveDataToStorage("Test", Test);       
        }
        
    }
}
```

My View code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="Bibliomatic_MAUI_App.Views.TestEditorView"
             xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:Bibliomatic_MAUI_App.Behaviors"
             xmlns:customControls="clr-namespace:Bibliomatic_MAUI_App.CustomControls"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Bibliomatic_MAUI_App.Models"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Bibliomatic_MAUI_App.ViewModels" 
             xmlns:selectors="clr-namespace:Bibliomatic_MAUI_App.Selectors"               
             x:DataType="viewModel:TestEditorViewModel"
             x:Name="TestEditorPage"
             Title="TestEditorView">   

    <ContentPage.Resources>

        <!-- Data templates -->

    </ContentPage.Resources>
    
    <StackLayout>

        <!-- Other ui elements -->
         <DataTemplate x:Type=models:TestQuestion>                       
       <Frame Padding="10" Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="Beige">
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <CheckBox x:Name="aspectCheckBox" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                                        <!- I bind image source here -->
                                        <Image x:Name="testQuestionImae" Source="{Binding QuestionImageSource}" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200">
                                            <Image.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference aspectCheckBox}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Aspect" Value="AspectFill"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference aspectCheckBox}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                                                    <Setter Property="Aspect" Value="AspectFit"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Image.Triggers>
                                        </Image>


                                    </StackLayout>
                                    

                                </Frame>                         
                                

    <!-- Other ui elements -->
        
        </DataTemplate>
    </StackLayout>
    
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: `Observable` doesn't automatically recurse to nested properties. Is `TestQuestion` also `ObservableObject`? Is its `QuestionImageSource` an `ObservableProperty`?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I use observable property inside my derived class and inside ui I bind to my derived model, so observable properties must work. Also I need to explain this. My Test class contains collection of TestQuestionResponce, which is base class of TestQuestion. So I fill TestQuestion collection with my derived class with observable properties

Comment: I asked a very specific question. I don't see how that is an answer to what I asked. Add to question the declaration of `TestQuestion`, and its `QuestionImageSource`. The point of "Observable" is to make sure **changes are seen**. Seeing the initial value doesn't mean it is working - any .net class and property can send in initial values.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve If I understand your question correctly, then in my ui, this element is linked to an inherited class that contains only observable properties. Should the base class also be an observable object? Because I don't understand how the properties of the base class that I don't use affect the observable properties of the inheritor class that I use to bind image source of my ui element

Comment: This is a confusing discussion unless we say actual class names. Before, all I knew for sure was that `TestEditorViewModel` was observable. Now that you show `TestQuestion` - it looks correct. I don't think its base class needs that, since there are no ObservablePropertys there. Maybe try `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () => selectedTestQuestion.QuestionImageSource = filepath );` Might not help; code is in a RelayCommand, so probably already on MainThread.  Sorry, I don't have any other ideas.